# How to stop panels from filling space in BoxLayout?

Tags: java, swing

I'm adding panels to a parent panel (rightPanel) with a BoxLayout, but I want it so that when the panels are added they remain the same size rather than resizing to fill the parent panel. The only way I've found of doing this is setting the max size, but I can't find a way to reliably set the max size to the correct absolute size. Either that or the text won't wrap correctly, and I want it so that the horizontal scroll bar is never used. The closest I've come is by getting the estimating the text height by creating a JLabel of html text that should be the same height, but this is unreliable, and the panel could have images in it so it could be thrown off. The reason I'm adding the text word by word is so that certain words will be replaced by images. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Main
{
    private static JPanel rightPanel;

    public static int getHeight(String text, int width, int fontSize)
    {
        final String html = "<html><body style='width: %1spx; font-size: %1spx;'>%1s";
        String formatted = String.format(html, width, fontSize, text);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(formatted);
        return label.getPreferredSize().height;
    }

    public static JPanel createTextPanel(String sender, String text)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel.setBackground(new Color(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(255), ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(255), ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(255)));

        JLabel name = new JLabel(sender + ":");
        panel.add(name);

        for (String word : text.split(" "))
        {
            if (isImage(word))
                panel.add(new JLabel(getImage(word)));
            else
                panel.add(new JLabel(word));
        }

        //Sorta close but not reliable
        int width = rightPanel.getPreferredSize().width;
        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, getHeight(text, width, 12)));
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();
        relativeLayout.setFill(true);

        Container container = frame.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(relativeLayout);

        JLabel centerPanel = new JLabel();
        centerPanel.setOpaque(true);
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        container.add(centerPanel, 0.8f);

        rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(rightPanel);
        container.add(scrollPane, 0.2f);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        rightPanel.setPreferredSize(rightPanel.getSize());

        String message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
        rightPanel.add(createTextPanel("Sender", message));
        rightPanel.add(createTextPanel("Sender", message));
        rightPanel.revalidate();
    }
}
```

How it looks right now:
[image]
How I want it to look:
[image]

Comment: The code in your question does not compile for me. Where is method `isImage`? Where is method `getImage`? What is class `RelativeLayout`? Consider posting a [mcve]. In the meantime, perhaps [How to Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) will help?

Comment: @Abra I thought it wasn't really relevant. It just looks up the word in a hashmap and returns an ImageIcon. That part can just be deleted and have it be: for (String word : text.split(" "))
   panel.add(new JLabel(word)); RelativeLayout is just a layout manager that has a component take up x percent of the container. https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/

Comment: In order for me to help you with your code, I initially need to copy it, compile it and run it and have it reproduce the behavior that you describe. Then I can start to change it and after I change it , test it to make sure that it produces your desired behavior. I believe anyone else who wants to help you will need to do the same thing. That's why I suggested that you post a [mcve]. I also suggest that you post the code for `RelativeLayout` in your question, rather than a link to it. Alternatively, you can just leave your question as is and hope that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: beware: don't set sizing constraints - if you do, you are most probably interfering with a layoutManager's job

Comment: the problem is the nesting of a FlowLayout in a BoxLayout: the latter respects the max of the children which is unbounded by default. The usual way out (implement the custom panel to report the pref as max) doesn't work because the former reports its sizing hints based on a single row (the wrapping happens only while doing the layout). A solution is to replace the FlowLayout - it's simply too weak (as are most in-built manager, IMO). Options to are to extend it yourself (see f.i. https://gist.github.com/jirkapenzes/4560255) or go for a full-fledge manager like MigLayout et al

Comment: btw: neither relativeLayout nor maxed frame are of any relevance here .. a plain BorderLayout with the box (containing) flows in a scrollpane is all that's needed to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm adding the text word by word is so that certain words will be replaced by images.

1. Instead of using a panel of JLabels, you can use a `JTextPane`. You can use the `setIcon(...)` method to insert images. The benefit of using a JTextPane is that it will automatically wrap the text for you based on the width of the text pane.
2. The next problem is that you need to restrict the width of the panel added to the viewport of the scroll pane so that the text can wrap automatically as the width of the scroll pane changes. To do this you can use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/).
3. Finally to limit the height of each text pane you can use a wrapper panel in the viewport with a `BorderLayout`. The rightPanel is then added to the `PAGE_START` which will respect the height of each component.

Putting it all together:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main
{
    private static JPanel rightPanel;

    public static int getHeight(String text, int width, int fontSize)
    {
        final String html = "<html><body style='width: %1spx; font-size: %1spx;'>%1s";
        String formatted = String.format(html, width, fontSize, text);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(formatted);
        return label.getPreferredSize().height;
    }

    public static JComponent createTextPanel(String sender, String text)
    {
/*
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel.setBackground(new Color(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(255), ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(255), ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(255)));

        JLabel name = new JLabel(sender + ":");
        panel.add(name);

        for (String word : text.split(" "))
        {
//            if (isImage(word))
//                panel.add(new JLabel(getImage(word)));
//            else
                panel.add(new JLabel(word));
        }

        //Sorta close but not reliable
//        int width = rightPanel.getPreferredSize().width;
//        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, getHeight(text, width, 12)));
//        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, getHeight(text, width, 12)));
        return panel;
*/
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText(text);
        textPane.setBackground(new Color(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(255), ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(255), ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(255)));

        return textPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();
        relativeLayout.setFill(true);

        Container container = frame.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(relativeLayout);

        JLabel centerPanel = new JLabel();
        centerPanel.setOpaque(true);
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        container.add(centerPanel, 0.8f);

        rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

//      JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        ScrollablePanel wrapper = new ScrollablePanel( new BorderLayout() );
        wrapper.setScrollableWidth( ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.FIT );
        wrapper.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(wrapper);
//        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(rightPanel);
        container.add(scrollPane, 0.2f);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

//        rightPanel.setPreferredSize(rightPanel.getSize());
//        wrapper.setPreferredSize(wrapper.getSize());

        String message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
        rightPanel.add(createTextPanel("Sender", message));
        rightPanel.add(createTextPanel("Sender", message));
        rightPanel.revalidate();
    }
}
```